# Remove range of elements from QHash

Tags: c++, qt, qhash, erase-remove-idiom

I use QHash as a container and I have a task to remove all items that satisfy the predicate.
At first I thought to use the [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) it turned out that QHash has no option to delete the range, but only a [function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qhash.html#erase) to delete a single element through the iterator.

std::unordered_map (which is conceptually close to the Qt's QHash) has the [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) of removing the range.

This implies a question: why QHash does not have a similar function and how to the best way remove items from the QHash satisfying the predicate?

Comment: how do you define *a range in unordered_map / hash map* ?

Comment: @PiotrS. based on their iterators. e.g. std::unordered_map::iterator

Comment: yes, but how do you define it? range of elements satisfying condition ? there is nothing like that in unordered_map, the result is implementation defined, because elements in unoredered_map are not ordered (as the name suggests itself)

Comment: @PiotrS. I know about unspecified ordering in unordered_map (sorry for tautology), but if we have iterators, we could have range based on them. Which could be passed to std::unordered_map::erase function. But QHash does not has it. Why?

Comment: because it is usless, even with unordered_map it is clearly stated that: (erase) *"Notice that unordered_map containers do not follow any particular order to organize its elements, therefore the effect of range deletions may not be easily predictable."*

Comment: @PiotrS. can you answer on a second part of original question "how to the best way remove items from the QHash satisfying the predicate", especially if we don't have range version of erase function?

Comment: [RTFM](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhash.html#erase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of the comments, it turns out that the erase-remove idiom does not apply to QHash container.

Therefore, given the description of the [QHash::erase](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qhash.html#erase), in particular that it does not violate the order of items in the hash

> Unlike remove() and take(), this function never causes QHash to rehash its internal data structure. This means that it can safely be called while iterating, and won't affect the order of items in the hash.

we have the following code to remove the elements that satisfy the predicate:

```
for( auto it = hash.begin(); it != hash.end(); )
{
    if( pred(*it) )
    {
        it = hash.erase(it); 
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work as it ignores the return value from erase() which is the iterator to the next item in the hash. You need to do;

```
QHash<QObject *, int> objectHash;
QHash<QObject *, int>::iterator i = objectHash.begin();
while (i != objectHash.end()) {
    if (i.value() == 0) {         // test here
        i = objectHash.erase(i);
    } else {
    ++i;
}
```

as per the Qt documentation link - otherwise you're incrementing an invalid iterator.